# User cannot add blog entry in page-scoped blog portlet on his public personal pages

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6, blogs, portlet

I have a in my opinion common use case for a public page of the users personal site in liferay. The user should be able to maintain a blog on such a public page. So I add a blog portlet to one of these pages and set the scope of the portlet to the page. It is necessary to set the scope to the page to enable the user to maintain more then one blog. Anyway, as soon as I change the scope the blog portlet is not working like expected. After this change the user is not able to add a blog entry or to do other things in the blog portlet because it is empty (no buttons visible). Otherwise when I do the same on a private page of the users personal site or on a public/private page of a normal site everything works like expected.

I'm a little bit suprised why this is not working because the use case (create blogs on public pages of personal sites) is described [here](http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen06-user-personal-sites-0). But I guess the change of the scope is not considered there.

Some additional information: I'm using liferay 6.2 (ce-ga4) with the social office extension. All permissions are set to fulfill the use case (e.g. the user has the right to add a blog entry on a users personal site).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who comes across the same problem: Apparently it is a bug: [LPS-57926](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-57926)